# Using PHP Class Variables from other class

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm having an issue with a set of code. I'm not able to get the variable to display.

Here is the function

```
    public function __construct($id = self::DHMeetingCommentCardNew, DHMeetingGroup $meetingGroup = null)
    {
        global $DB;

        if ($id == self::DHMeetingCommentCardNew)
        {
            var_dump($meetingGroup);
            $query = "INSERT INTO `" . self::DHMeetingCommentCardTable . "` (`UniqueID`, `MeetingGroup`) VALUES (UUID(), '{$meetingGroup['_id']}')";
            $DB->query($query);

            $this->_id = $DB->lastID();
            $this->_initializeNewCommentCard();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_id = intval($id);
        }
    }
```

I can't get the ID out of the $meetingGroup variable.

For the var_dump($meetingGroup) it dumps this.

```
NULL object(DHMeetingGroup)#10745 (1) { ["_id":"DHMeetingGroup":private]=> int(11086) }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as property is defined as `property` you can only access it from the same instance (and same class), not outside.

The only thing you can do is to change how `_id` property is declared in `DHMeetingGroup` from `private` to `public`

Comment: I changed the definition from private to public and now the var_dump is putting this out.

Comment: @user764429: I don't get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code to your class DHMeetingGroup

```
public function get_id()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

and then changing this row (in the class i'm guessing is called DHMeetingCommentCard)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . self::DHMeetingCommentCardTable . "` (`UniqueID`, `MeetingGroup`) VALUES (UUID(), '{$meetingGroup['_id']}')";
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . self::DHMeetingCommentCardTable . "` (`UniqueID`, `MeetingGroup`) VALUES (UUID(), '{$meetingGroup->get_id()}')";
```